# Link to Play Store - Smart App Banner - Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-play, smartbanner

I have red the documentation for Smart App Banner iOS. This is fine and i implemented it on my website. The problem is that the documentation says:

> Because of the fragmentation of the Android ecosystem and browser
>   choice, Google has never released an Android smart banner. All Android
>   developers have had to roll their own or adapt a pre-existing solution. Reference: https://blog.branch.io/how-to-setup-an-ios-and-android-smart-app-banner-with-deep-linking-and-download-tracking/
>   .

Now ive searched for some answers and seen multiple answers but i cannot still determind if im thinking right.

**There are some people who are linking to:**

- https://github.com/kudago/smart-app-banner
- https://github.com/ain/smartbanner.js

Now my question is. **Are these the same as the release Google had for App Install Banners?** Link: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/native

Is this the same as "smart app banner" for iOS? This looks little different for me as it says "Add to Home Screen" and "App Install Prompt (native)".

Someone build this solution before?

Answer (score 0):

I have built [this solution](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/native) before, but the documentation made it more confusing. I simplified the Android native app install prompt documentation. There is a native banner that appears for Android if you follow [my steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66699710/14621307).

The js and jquery packages try to match the style of the ios smart app banner as well as the device's ui.