# Native App Install Prompt on Chrome - anyone got it working?

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to follow [this documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/app-install-banners-native/) to add a Native App Install Prompt to my site, but not seeing anything happen on my site. So far I have:

- Added a manifest.json and `<link>` tag
- Added the .png icons
- Ensure the page is being served over HTTPS

I've tried testing using Browserstack set to Chrome on Samsung Galaxy S20, but I'm not seeing anything happen at all - anyone have any guidance, advice, working examples?

Adding the iOS Smart App banner was straightforward but not having any success with the Android equivalent at all.

Comment: Hey, the Android Install banner requires some additional network configuration during testing for it to work, could you please follow the steps demonstrated in this video tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9whdWJ4q7jE

Thanks.

Comment: This has been [asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55838392/how-exactly-are-we-supposed-to-implement-the-native-app-install-prompt-for-chrom/66699710#66699710)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How exactly are we supposed to implement the Native App Install Prompt for Chrome on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55838392/how-exactly-are-we-supposed-to-implement-the-native-app-install-prompt-for-chrom)